# How to add or change an axis to an image in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am attempting python for the first time.  My end game have an image with an x-axis of distance in meters and a y-scale of depth (m) showing a 500x500m grid.
I was able to plot the grid onto the image two different ways, both ways utilize pixel size for the grid spacing themselves.  A simple distance to pixel ratio is used to get accurate grid spacing.

The first attempt (using matplotlib), I was able to create an accurate grid spacing with incorrect axes (the axes reflect pixels, no clue how to change the axes values without changing grid spacing).

The second code (using PIL) produces an Image with only grids and no axes at all, only grids

Im sure the answer to my problem is buried inside the PIL or matplotlib documentation, but I am new to python and am still learning the conventions , and even how libraries work

Is there a way to draw axes around an image?  Or would it simply be easier to make a custom scale that does not relate to pixels somehow with matplotlib?

I know this is a very vague question, but could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Either way should work, it all depends on your use case and end goal. Check the documentation for matplotlib to set the correct axes or use PIL to manually draw a grid with axes wherever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want axes, use matplotlib `imshow`. If you have the pixel to distance ratio, e.g. "1 pixel = 100 meters", you can use it to set the `extent` if the image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = np.random.rand(5,5)

#1 pixel = 100 meters
r = 1./100.

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(image, extent=(0,image.shape[1]/r,0,image.shape[0]/r) )
ax.set_xlabel("distance [m]")
ax.set_ylabel("distance [m]")  

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer to the poorly written question.  I am new to the community and coding in general (so sorry again for the bad quastion), this answer really helped get me on the right track!  Thank you for your help!